# Flutter Firebase Error - Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app was working fine few days ago, when i try to Login or signup i am getting this error now. I have tried all the solutions found in the internet. I am facing this issue only in android, IOS is working fine.

Below is my code.

Login and Register functions.

```
Future signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      try {
        await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then((value) {
          MySharedPreferences.instance
              .setBooleanValue("loggedin", true);
          Get.to(() => const MobileNumberScreen());
        });
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        switch (error.code) {
          //error information
        }
        // print("Login Error:: " + error.toString());
      }
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = AutovalidateMode.always;
      });
    }
  }

Future signUp(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
      try {
        await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password).then((value) => addUser());
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
        print('Error:$error');
        switch (error.code) {
          //error information
        }
        setState(() {
          _autoValidate = AutovalidateMode.always;
        });
        print("Registration Error" + error.code);
      }
    }
  }
```

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: What versions of the Firebase packages are you using?

Comment: firebase_core: ^1.15.0.            
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.13.         
firebase_auth: ^3.3.16